# Find by object attribute spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have two class :

1. -->User(id/username(string)/password(string))
2. -->Role(id/role(string)/user(User))

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="Utilisateur")
   public class User {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private long id;
     private String username;
     private String password;
   } 

   @Entity                 
   public class Role {    
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private long id;
     private String role;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     private User user ;
   }
   ```

how to write  a function in `RoleRepository` that find Role by username in user

I try `List<Role> findByUsername(String username)` but not work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write *findByUsername* in RoleRepository. There is no username property for Role. The following functions solve the problem.

```
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {
    List<Role> findRoleByUser_Username(String username);
    List<Role> findByUser_Username(String username);
}
```